# URL value to indicate an empty parameter (not in the query string)?

Tags: api, rest, url

Is there a standard character or way to indicate the absence of a parameter in a URL?

- `/some/[empty]/interesting/[empty]/url` ?
- `/some/-/interesting/-/url` ?
- `/some/_/interesting/_/url` ?

Background:

- I have a RESTful API which allows to call certain actions on an resource of a certain type: `/my-resource/1234/do-something`.
- However, some actions need not be run against any specific resource. So far, we've enabled that by simply specifying no ID in the url: `/my-resource//do-something-else`.
- However, we are just discovering that some Web servers and proxies strip multiple slashes, transforming the previous URL into: `/my-resource/do-something`, which is a bad URL (it's trying to read `do-something` as an ID).
- We need both methods to work on the same resource (with & without ID), so using multiple routes is not an option, and we don't want to change the URL structure.

Is there a standard/mainstream way of indicating the absence of an ID in similar URLs? So far, we're thinking of going with a dash: `/my-resource/-/do-something`.

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen leads me to believe you should simply omit the irrelevant portions.

The documentation for the framework you're using should have the priority rules for parsing URLs. You should be fine as long as the patterns with the wildcards have lower priority.

For example, assuming an API that deals with multiple inventories, you could obtain either a JSON representation, or the safety data-sheets with these endpoints:

```
users/:userId/inventory/:inventoryId
users/:userId/inventory/:inventoryId/items/dataSheet # A aggregate data-sheet for the location
users/:userId/inventory/:inventoryId/items/:itemId
users/:userId/inventory/:inventoryId/items/:itemId/dataSheet # Just for this item

# This example is a tad facetious, as this would probably be better:
# users/:userId/inventory/:inventoryId/dataSheet
#
# But it is just an example.
```

As the IDs should be UUIDs, there is no chance a user would mistake `inventory/dataSheet` for `inventory/129c00d0a78a48318ea8aa0c66d93ddb`. Additionally, this makes it clear what influences the PDF you get from `/inventory/dataSheet`.

Comparing these, I find that the second telegraphs more clearly the intent:

```
/users/b02e...531e/inventory/7471...dcad/items/-/dataSheet
/users/b02e...531e/inventory/7471...dcad/dataSheet
```

Particularly as the difference between these is unclear:

```
/users/b02e...531e/inventory/7471...dcad/items/-/dataSheet
/users/b02e...531e/inventory/7471...dcad/items/bf7f...9525/dataSheet
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. We need both URLs to work (with ID or without ID). Route priority won't help us since we're only using a single, generic route: `/{resource}/{id}/{action}`. Creating multiple routes is not an option. I'll update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Any particular reason multiple routes are not an option? I ask because I've never seen the situation  you're describing.

Comment: We want to maintain a standard URL structure across all endpoints, which makes it easier for the consumers to use the API, and the framework we use also expects this. It allows us to create new endpoints in a matter of minutes, and we want to keep it that way. And also, we need the URLs to work both with or without an ID. If we were to create separate routes, we would have to identify them somehow. Ex: `/my-resource/id/1234/do-something` & `/my-resource/no-id/do-something-else`. We also want to avoid that, in order to keep the URLs as short, clean & generic as possible.

Comment: Isn't that misleading? It implies these endpoints actually require the IDs that are being omitted.

Comment: I've worked with a lot of people developing and using these APIs, and it's the first time I get this feedback. I guess it depends how explicit and strict you want to be with your routes. Either way, I think short & clean URLs trump almost everything else, and most people seem to agree, including search engines.

Comment: I'm sorry if that came across wrong. I certainly didn't intend to imply that you hadn't put considerable thought into your API. I favor omitting information that is not used for that very reason, it tends to result in short and clean URLs. I'll update the answer with an example.